# How to build solution projects in VSO for ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net, .net, configuration, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-devops

I want to setup building of my ASP.NET 5 project in VSO.
The Solution has several projects:

```
Solution    
    Project1
    Project2
    WebSite
```

The problem is dependencies on Project1 and Project2 set in project.json and when I run PowerShell script for resolving all dependencies, projects in solution not found. I skip it, but build of solution failed too, because it can't find these projects.

How to configure building in VSO to build non default projects?

Answer (score 0):

If you **work with the vNext build system** in VSO, all you need to do is to check the **Restore NuGet Packages** checkbox in the build definition, and choose the .sln file you would like to build.

[image]

If you **work with one XAML build definition**, there are some steps (described [here](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build)) you need to follow in order to have these NuGet packages restored during the VSO (TFS) build process.

1. Add following items to the solution. (Content of the nuget.config and .tfignore file can be found [here](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build))

[image]

2. Add one build.proj file under the root path of the solution folder. (Content of the build.proj file can be found [here](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build))
3. Create one folder named **tools** under the root path of the solution folder. Create **NuGet** sub-folder under **tools** folder, download and save [nuget.exe](https://www.nuget.org/nuget.exe) under tools\NuGet path.
4. Check in **nuget.config**, **.tfignore**, **build.proj** and **tools\NuGet\nuget.exe** into TFS version control.
5. Modify the build definition to choose to build the build.proj file.
   [image]

Then you will have NuGet packages restored successfully during the TFS build process.

Comment: Projects are successfully built locally. project doesn't have .nuget folder and links on it.